# CakePHP Auth ignored when accessing cached view with certain routing of '/'

Tags: cakephp, authentication, caching, routes, cakephp-1.3

I have Views Caching set up on the index action of my controller using

```
class DiaryController extends AppController {
  ...
  var $cacheAction = array('index' => "+56 hours");

  function index($week = null) {
    ...
  }
}
```

with the following options in `app/config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Cache.check', true);

...

Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

The index action on the diary controller (and the rest of the site!) should only be accessible to authenticated users, using the `AuthComponent` with

```
class AppController extends Controller {

  ...
  var $components = array('Auth', 'Security', 'Session','Cookie','RequestHandler');

  function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Admin';
    ...
  }
...
}
```

I want to map the root of the site to my login form using

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'login'));
```

in `app/config/routes.php`. All appears to work okay, until I log out and then try to visit `mytestsite.com/diary/index` in the browser. I can still access the pages even though I am not logged in. I believe this is an issue with the caching because I can only access the urls which I have files for in `app/tmp/cache/views`. Changing the `$week` parameter for the index action to a value that I do not have a cache file for results in a `You are not authorized to access that location.` message.

The strange thing is that if I map the root of the site to the index action of the `DiaryController`, with

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'diary', 'action' => 'index'));
```

(again in `app/config/routes.php`) I don't have this problem.I cannot access the cached diary index views when I am not logged in.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Can you suggest something I might have missed? Or do you know if this is a bug in the core files? I am using CakePHP 1.3.15.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response, but the reason is that caching a view action bypasses all controller and component callbacks. The Auth component does its stuff via callbacks. So, when you cache an action, those checks are ignored.

You can force callbacks to fire by passing a 'callbacks' => true option in $cacheAction, like this:

```
public $cacheAction = array(
    'index' => array('callbacks' => true, 'duration' => '+56 hours')
);
```

But that partially defeats the purpose of view caching, which is to bypass all of the controller logic.

More info [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html).